# Vuforia Android on HTC ONE app crash?

Tags: android, eclipse, augmented-reality, vuforia

I followed this tutorial and made my app by compiling it with vuforia in unity.

Tutorial i followed was: https://developer.vuforia.com/resources/dev-guide/step-2-compiling-simple-project

My phone is htc one with jelly bean on, the app i'm compiling i used the following settings:

bundle identifier:com.mycompany.firstARapp
minimum api level: android 2.3.1 honeycomb api level 9
device filter: armv7only
install location: prefer external
graphics level: opengl es 2.0

here is a link to my apk:http://www.sendspace.com/file/eg54rz

the app is a simple target i made on the dev site with a cube on it.

the marker i am using is http://www.immersivetech.org/wp-content/uploads/2009/09/ImTech_Marker.jpg

Problem i have is the app says it instals when i click open it just shuts and closes.

Comment: What does the logcat show after the app crashes?

Comment: How do i check the logcat please?

Comment: W/IINPUTConnectionWrapper(14077): reportFullScreenMode on inactive inputconnection